# Question about a Möbius transformation/Conformal map

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I have a question about a conformal mapping. The map $f(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ takes the unit disk to the right half plane. Composing this map with $z^2$ gives $f(z)=(\frac{1+z}{1-z})^2$, which I think gives me the whole complex plane, except for the negative real axis. But how can I easily see (without trial and error computations) that the negative real axis will be excluded.

Thankful for any help with this!

Comment: Are we talking about the open unit disk or the closed one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include the boundary of the disk in your domain, then the boundary of the right half-plane will be in the image of $f$, and the negative real axis will be in the image of $z\mapsto f(z)^2$.

Your first function takes the upper half of the boundary to the upper half of the imaginary axis.  If you include the upper half of the circle, including $-1$ but excluding $1$, that maps to the upper half of the imaginary axis including $0$ but excluding $\infty$, and then squaring takes that to the negative real axis including $0$ but excluding $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Okey, so you're saying that if we consider the closed unit disk, then the mapping won't exclude the negative real axis. But it has to exclude something right? Doesn't Riemanns mapping theorem say that you can't map the unit disk onto the whole complex plane? (Or is it the exclusion of the point at infinity that takes care of that?)

Secondly, is it then true that the mapping would exclude the negative real axis if we were to consider the open unit disk?

Comment: I don't know how the Riemann mapping theorem could be taken to imply that.  The Riemann mapping theorem says that for every simply connected open subset $U$ of $\mathbb C$ except $\mathbb C$ there is a holomorphic bijection $f$ from the open unit disk to $U$ whose inverse is also holomorphic.  It doesn't say whether there is such a mapping if $U=\mathbb C$, but the non-existence of such a thing follows from Liouiville's theorem applied to $f^{-1}$.  However, the mapping $z\mapsto \left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^2$ on the closed disk is not invertible, and${}\,\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$the Riemann mapping theorem doesn't say anything about mappings from the closed disk as far as I know. ${}\qquad{}$